# Only Allowing One Menu at a Time to be Opened - React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Preface: I'm new to React and JavaScript in general, so please excuse formatting or lack of knowledge when it comes to recommended usage.

So I'm using Tailwind UI as a base for the site and it comes with these navigation menus, which doesn't come with any CSS for opening and closing the menu, relying completely on JavaScript. I've gotten it working as shown below, but now I'm stumped on how I can prevent one menu to be opened at a time. I do have it working, however when clicking another menu while one is open, it just closes the other menu, doesn't really open the actual menu the user clicks on. I have an example of my code below, maybe there's a better way to handle it?

EDIT: Someone suggested to re-create the code in CodeSandbox so here you go.

https://codesandbox.io/s/sweet-goodall-5wn8r

Comment: Could you recreate your code in CodeSandbox? That way we have a working example.

Comment: Looks like the codesandbox is not completely working correctly, you still need to edit your `App.js` to display something else than the default code.

Comment: @Titulum I did. Are you not seeing the updated code? Try again, it's working fine for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like I can get it working by using the following in my NavBar function:

```js
const [isOpen2, setIsOpen2] = useState(false);
const [isOpen1, setIsOpen1] = useState(false);
const toggle1 = () => {
   if (isOpen2) toggle2();
      setIsOpen1(!isOpen1);
   };
const toggle2 = () => {
   if (isOpen1) toggle1();
      setIsOpen2(!isOpen2);
   };
```

The code in the CodeSandbox is toggling the menus multiple times, and I didn't catch that until now. Hope this helps others that use Tailwind UI!

Answer (score 0):

i think you are trying to do this.

https://codesandbox.io/s/festive-taussig-uh4lk